# Imprimir atributo list de uma classe no xml

Tags: java, xml

Como posso gerar uma arquivo xml em java, a partir de uma classe que recebe um ArrayList como atributo. Não estou conseguindo acessar os indices desse Arraylist no momento de passar para a string que sera gravada no xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não sei qual lib você está usando pra serializar os objetos em XML, mas geralmente eu uso [Xstream](http://x-stream.github.io/).

No caso de serializar uma lista de produtos de um objeto `Carrinho` que possui uma lista de produtos:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream();
xstream.alias("Produtos", List.class);
xstream.toXML(carrinho.getProdutos());
```

Comment: Qualquer coisa, manda teu código que dou uma olhada...